# How to let users provide multiple answers dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have to design a Google Form wherein users can provide multiple responses to a particular question. The number of responses can vary from user to user and does not have a fixed upper limit (Would mostly never go above 20 but still can't put a number on it). For example:

**Response 1**

```
Name: John
Age: 26
Answer: Apple
Banana
```

**Response 2**

```
Name: Mike
Age: 28
Answer: Guava
Mango
Orange
```

Now, this is how I want this data to look in the spreadsheet:

```
Name  Age  Answer
John  26   Apple 
John  26   Banana
Mike  28   Guava
Mike  28   Mango 
Mike  28   Orange
```

How to achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have some code to start on with?

Comment: Sorry no. New to Google Apps scripting. Not even sure how to start.